# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable Magento2 Error no flag

Tags: magento2, nginx

I was trying to print an order collection array (\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory), but it never gets printed, I know the reason.

Now when I reload my browser, I get a `503 Service Temporarily Unavailable` everywhere, frontend and backend.

There is no `maintenance.flag` or even `.maintenance.flag` anywhere in var/ folder.

Mode - developer,
Hosted on NGINX, plesk (other sites on same server working). I tried deleting cache, indexing, static contents deploy everything.

The error in /var/log/nginx/error.log is:

> 2018/02/22 11:36:56 [notice] 9870#0: signal process started
>   2018/02/22 11:36:56 [error] 9870#0: open() "/var/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Kindly help!

Comment: Did you try looking in the Apache/Nginx error logs?

Comment: Any recent changes? Are you using Apache or NginX?

Comment: I am using nginx

Comment: @EthanYehuda i have updated my question

Comment: @KumarA. I have posted the answer, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Reload your NginX configuration:*

If your system has systemctl

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

If your system supports service (using debian/ubuntu) try this

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

If not (using centos/fedora/etc) you can try the init script

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

Please make sure that you **reload** and not restart.

- Reloading keeps the server running while re-reading any configuration file updates.
- Reloading is safer than restarting because if a syntax error is noticed in a config file, it will not proceed with the reload and your server remains running.
- If there is a syntax error in a config file and you restart, it's possible the server will not restart correctly.

Comment: easy to run just `nginx -t` .many times seen it will restart/reload without any messages... this is not magento issue anyway. then afterall you must check if pid is running `ps aux | grep nginx`

Comment: Sorry for my late response, but restarting nginx worked. However, i cannot manage to get any solution to core reason of this, but for now i am ready to move ahead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**FOR AN NGINX / PHPFPM / VARNISH SETUP**

I grappled with this for a while this worked for me :

service php7.1-fpm restart

**NB**
*You will need to find the relevant php service for your environment : 
sudo service --status-all and see which phpfpm is in your list*